# Drupal using a template file for a block

Tags: module, drupal-7, block

I have the following structure in my module

```
- my module
  - templates
    mytemplate.tpl.php
```

and a block

```
function myblock_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'myblock') {



    return $block;
  }    
}
```

How do I use the tpl as the block content?

Answer (score 2):

define a theme using [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and specify path of your template in it as below

```
function hook_theme() {
  $theme = array(
    'custom_template' => array(
    'template' => '/templates/mytemplate',
  ));
  return $theme;
}
```

then in your [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) do below

```
function myblock_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'myblock') {
    $block['content'] = theme('custom_template');
    return $block;
  }    
}
```